# Jquery multiple file uploader sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multiple file uploader that was originally designed to only have 1 uploading section:
[Codepen Single Upload Section](http://codepen.io/heavenkinder/details/MeyOwj/)

After that, i had the need to add more than 1 uploading section. After that i started having problems:
[Codepen Multiple Upload Section](http://codepen.io/heavenkinder/pen/XKKBBa)

On my website i need 6 upload sections. What i've been trying was to have a onchange function for each `file-chooser_input`. Once it changes, it performs every function needed for it to function properly.

Example:

```
    //jQuery plugin
(function( $ ) {

   $.fn.uploader = function( options ) {
     var settings = $.extend({
       MessageAreaText: "There is no file selected.",
       MessageAreaTextWithFiles: "File list:",
       DefaultErrorMessage: "Failed opening file.",
       BadTypeErrorMessage: "Invalid type of file.",
       acceptedFileTypes: ['pdf', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'tif', 'tiff', 'png','doc', 'docx']
     }, options );

     var uploadId = 1;
     //update the messaging 
      $('.file-uploader__message-area_section1 p').text(options.MessageAreaText || settings.MessageAreaText);

      $('.file-uploader__message-area_section2 p').text(options.MessageAreaText || settings.MessageAreaText);

     //create and add the file list and the hidden input list

    //when choosing a file, add the name to the list and copy the file input into the hidden inputs
     $('.file-chooser__input_section1').on('change', function(){
     var fileList = $('<ul class="file-list_section1"></ul>');
     var hiddenInputs = $('<div class="hidden-inputs_section1 hidden"></div>');
     $('.file-uploader__message-area_section1').after(fileList);
     $('.file-list_section1').after(hiddenInputs);
        var file = $('.file-chooser__input_section1').val();
        var fileName = (file.match(/([^\\\/]+)$/)[0]);

       //clear any error condition
       $('.file-chooser_section1').removeClass('error');
       $('.error-message').remove();

       //validate the file
       var check = checkFile(fileName);
       if(check === "valid") {

         // move the 'real' one to hidden list 
         $('.hidden-inputs_section1').append($('.file-chooser__input_section1')); 

         //insert a clone after the hiddens (copy the event handlers too)
         $('.file-chooser_section1').append($('.file-chooser__input_section1').clone({ withDataAndEvents: true})); 

         //add the name and a remove button to the file-list
         $('.file-list_section1').append('<li style="display: none;"><span class="file-list__name">' + fileName + '</span><button class="removal-button" data-uploadid="'+ uploadId +'"></button></li>');
         $('.file-list_section1').find("li:last").show(800);

         //removal button handler
         $('.removal-button').on('click', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

           //remove the corresponding hidden input
           $('.hidden-inputs_section1 input[data-uploadid="'+ $(this).data('uploadid') +'"]').remove(); 

           //remove the name from file-list that corresponds to the button clicked
           $(this).parent().hide("puff").delay(10).queue(function(){$(this).remove();});

           //if the list is now empty, change the text back 
           if($('.file-list_section1 li').length === 0) {
             $('.file-uploader__message-area_section1').text(options.MessageAreaText || settings.MessageAreaText);
           }
         });
         //so the event handler works on the new "real" one
         $('.hidden-inputs_section1 .file-chooser__input_section1').removeClass('file-chooser__input_section1').attr('data-uploadId', uploadId); 

         //update the message area
         $('.file-uploader__message-area_section1').text(options.MessageAreaTextWithFiles || settings.MessageAreaTextWithFiles);

         uploadId++;

       } else {
         //indicate that the file is not ok
         $('.file-chooser_section1').addClass("error");
         var errorText = options.DefaultErrorMessage || settings.DefaultErrorMessage;

         if(check === "badFileName") {
           errorText = options.BadTypeErrorMessage || settings.BadTypeErrorMessage;
         }

         $('.file-chooser__input_section1').after('<p class="error-message">'+ errorText +'</p>');
       }
     });

//REPEAT SECTION 2

}( jQuery ));

//init 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fileUploader').uploader({
    MessageAreaText: "Select a file."
  });
});
```

It hasn't been working out and i still haven't figured out how to have the 6 functions "isolated" and working properly. I dont know what else to try. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Sorry i didn't specify the problem. The problem is after you upload the second file. No matter in what section, or if you remove the previous one, it adds 2 fields, and 2 files to the list. and that will keep on going and adding more and more file inputs and files to the list.

Comment: What exactly the problem? The thing that I see that once you choose a file, then remove it, then upload again, 2 input files added. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem is after you upload the second file. No matter in what section, or if you remove the previous one, it adds 2 fields, and 2 files to the list.

Comment: unclear your asked qwuestion

Comment: Sorry i didn't especify the problem.

Comment: A. Why do you call the plugin on element `.fileUploader` which not exist? B. When you create plugin you shouldn't treat to root element only to element who related the the element you run the plugin on it. For example: if you call the plugin on element `.fileUploader` you can find an element **within** it. I think you need to read more about [how to create a jQuery plugin](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/writing-your-own-jquery-plugins)

Comment: @MoshFeu Wow that's a major distraction. So what i need to do is wrap the html uploading section into a `<div class="fileUploader">` so it calls the plugin in all the uploading sections?

Comment: Why are you using a plugin? Why not just use regular functions? Do you have `.file-list_section1` (**for example**) for **each** input? Also, you create `.fileList` in **each** `change` event. I assume that you don't want this.

Comment: @MoshFeu I was using a template and i adapted it my way and as you can see it didn't work out well. So i would only have a change function for each input right? And yes i have a `file-list` for each input (`file-list_section"section number"`). I didn't understand what you said about creating a `.fileList` in each `change` event. Isn't that what i'm already doing?

Comment: If you have multiple inputs with the **same** behavior, plugin is good. But in your code `.file-chooser__input_section1` - I believe that it should be generic  `.file-chooser__input_section + some_index`. Look, it's pretty long to explain how to write plugin right. Please read some articles and write the code according them. Then, if you got stuck I will happy to help you..

Comment: @MoshFeu I've been stuck with this for over a week, i've been reading about plugins to be able to go around, i'm only missing a few concepts but i really need to finish this cause this has been too much time spent trying to fix this bug. I really need your help. please

Comment: If I will have a free time I will help you. But right now I have not. Sorry..